# Ubuntu MD5 File

Tags: system-installation

How do I find the actual MD5 file on ubuntu's website to compare the download with? I am trying to verify the ubuntu-22.04.3-desktop-amd64 download file for a computer class I am taking. I just need the original MD5 checksum to compare it to.

Comment: The original MD5 was only created long ago for older releases; then the reason for switching to SHA256 was blogged (ML I suspect) about & no more MD5s were created for ISOs. You can use a search engine to find the blog (*I don't recall the link as was years! ago*) but it was never created for any 22.04 release!  Any **original MD5** will be for much older releases.

Comment: As side note... There is even a zsync file that uses as _strong_ checksum for the blocks to transfer the MD4 checksum (yes you read well MD4 not MD5)... Read more [here](http://zsync.moria.org.uk/paper/ch02s03.html)... BTW under windows from command line `certutil -hashfile C:\Users\user1\ubuntu-22.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso SHA256`, under Linux `sha256sum /path/to/your/file/ubuntu-22.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso`...

Answer (score 11):

Canonical does not provide a MD5 checksum anymore, as this is based on today's safety standards too weak. However, a SHA256 checksum is provided.
The SHA256 checksum can be found on the download page, see https://releases.ubuntu.com/22.04.3/ for Ubuntu 22.04.3.

Details on how to verify: [see this Ubuntu tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview).